# SOP violation on ios UIWebView, but not FF desktop after CORS implemented?

Tags: gwt, uiwebview, jetty

I'm loading my GWT project from domain A, then trying to fetch some data from another one of my servers which is at a different domain (B). So I ran into the SOP violation issue. To work around this, I implemented CORS on server B.
Now the SOP problem has gone away when running through Firefox desktop. I then tried running the same code in a UIWebView on ios. I seem to be getting an SOP violation though:

```
public class MyRequestCallback implements RequestCallback {

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 0) {
                // Is this a SOP violation?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the connection takes some time (so looks like the request is going out), but then I just get a status code of zero back.

Has anyone run into something like this? Hard to figure out where to post this, as it touches a few different parts of the stack. Maybe there's a property on UIWebView I need to set to tell it its ok to use CORS?

To implement CORS on my server (I'm using jetty), I used:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter

Thanks

----- Update ------

This is how my filter is defined in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

both the FF client, and the ios client are hitting my one test endpoint.

Comment: Which origins are you allowing? Turn the CrossOriginFilter log to the _debug_ level and look at the log; is there any noticeable difference between Firefox and iOS UIWebView?

Comment: Hi Thomas, updated above. I'll look into this logging you mentioned, not familiar with it - will try to find a difference as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I launched jetty, now using:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner

instead of:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Run_Jetty

Running my war using runner, the cross origin request works fine. This is true for both the version of jetty I was using (v7.3), and the version I updated to as a result of this question, v7.6.9. So the way I was starting jetty previously probably had some kind of mistake in it.

Thanks